# Trying to sort the dates from newest to oldest on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

The dates on this column are filled in by a formula. Something about the formula i think might be causing my issue. This is the formula:
=QUERY({Tables!A1:K;Chairs!A1:K}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col11) where Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1",1)

I tried to click sort from Z-A and it switches it momentarily but then automatically switches it back the next second. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: the sorting must be foreseen in the formula itself ... try this: `=QUERY({Tables!A1:K;Chairs!A1:K}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col11) WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 desc",1)`

Comment: YES!, thank you!